# Laravel <br> to newline

Tags: php, html, json, laravel, parsing

I know I can do a simple replace when wanting to convert `<br>` tags to new lines. But I am facing a problem with parsing because provided `<br>` tags are not empty.

```
<br style=\"color: rgb(83, 83, 83); font-family: \" helvetica=\"\" ...
```

Back end is not mine, so there is no point in discussing about good or bad coding here, I am just wondering if there is a solution to replace those with simple new lines.

Something like `nl2br()` but reverse.

**EDIT:**

Don't know what use is to show code when I know 'why' is the thing that I've tried not working...but here goes

```
public function removeSingleHtmlFormatting($single)
{
    $single->short_description = str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $single->short_description);
    $single->short_description = strip_tags($single->description);
    $single->short_description = preg_replace("/&nbsp;/", " ", $single->short_description);
}
```

Of course replace doesn't work because there is no such string to replace...I have no idea where to start parsing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
str_replace("<br>", "\r\n", $single->short_description);
```

try

```
preg_replace("/<br.*>/U", "\r\n", $single->short_description);
```

This way the regular expression matches `<br>` including anything inside it, not only empty `<br>`.